# Returned hashtable does not display all columns

Tags: powershell

I can't get my PowerShell script to return additional rows when the hashtable is returned.

```powershell
Param(
    [array]$ArrayItem = ("Hello","to","the","World")
)
$inLine = @()
[int]$i=0
foreach ($item in $ArrayItem) {
    $tracking = $null
    $RandomNum = Get-Random -Maximum 100
    $tracking = $($ArrayItem[$i])
    Write-Host $tracking" - "$RandomNum
    $properties = @{}
        $properties = @{
         Title = "Tracking-"+$i
         Date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time -Format "HH:mm:ss"
         $tracking = $RandomNum
    }
    #$properties.Add($tracking,$RandomNum)
    #$properties | Add-Member -MemberType PropertySet -Name $tracking -Value $get
    $inLine += New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -property $properties
    $i++
}
$inLine
```

I wasn't sure what to do. Here is the output. It's missing "to", "the" and "world." Only the first column displays.

```
Date     Title      Hello
----     -----      -----
15:56:59 Tracking-0    70
15:56:59 Tracking-1
15:56:59 Tracking-2
15:56:59 Tracking-3
```

It should look like this

```
Date     Title      Hello     to     the     world
----     -----      -----     --     ---     -----
15:56:59 Tracking-0    70
15:56:59 Tracking-1           23 
15:56:59 Tracking-2                   45
15:56:59 Tracking-3                             53
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The expected output from your code is very confusing and most likely going the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would get you the desired output, however it's very likely there is a simpler solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

```bash
Param(
    [array] $ArrayItem = ('Hello', 'to', 'the', 'World')
)

$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ArrayItem.Length; $i++) {
    $current = $ArrayItem[$i]
    $out = [ordered]@{
        Date  = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time -Format 'HH:mm:ss'
        Title = 'Tracking-' + $i
    }

    foreach ($property in $ArrayItem) {
        if ($property -eq $current) {
            $out[$property] = Get-Random -Maximum 100
            continue
        }

        $out[$property] = ''
    }

    [pscustomobject] $out
}

$result | Format-Table
```